# Using Quaternion Extension of Eulers Formula what is $e^{qw} * e^{qw} = e^{qw2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions, eulers-method

Knowing that for quaternions Euler's identity is:

> $q = a + bi + cj + dk$  *with a,b,c,d real numbers*
>
> $\sqrt{b^2+ c^2 + d^2} = r > 0$
>
> $e^q = e^{a + r\sqrt{-1}} = e^ae^{r\sqrt{-1}} = e^a(\cos(r) + \sqrt{-1} \sin(r)) = e^a(\cos(r) + \frac{\sin(r)}{r}(bi + cj + dk))$

Using above method, where $e^q = e^ae^{r\sqrt{-1}}$, what is $d^ne^{nx\sqrt{-1}}*e^q$ ?

**Edit:**
The original question above utilized a flawed assumption that a quaternion $e^q$ could be multiplied directly by a simple complex number set $d^n(a+bi)^n$=$d^ne^{nx\sqrt{-1}}$. After discovering this mistake the revision of the question is as follows.

**By converting the complex number set into a quaternion using Cayley-Dickson construction:**

> $e^{x\sqrt{-1}} = e^{ix} = a + bi$
>
> $q = a + bi + cj + dk$ with a,b,c,d real numbers from single complex
>   number set
>
> Complex numbers are defined in terms of real numbers, such that:
>
> $z = a + bi, i^2=−1$
>
> Same process with two complex numbers [produces quaternion] :
>
> $qw = z1 + z2j$, $j^2=−1, ij=−ji=k$,
>
> $qw = a + bi + aj + bij$
>
> $\equiv$ $qw = a + bi + aj + bk$

Given the above method -

Complex number:
$d^n(a+bi)^n = d^ne^{nxi}$

as quaternion would be:
*[correct me if I'm wrong here]*

$qw = d^na^n + d^nb^ni + d^na^nj + d^nb^nk$

---

**Updated questions -**

1. **What is $e^{qw}$ using Euler's Formula Extension?**
2. **What is $e^{qw} * e^{qw} = e^{qw2}$, where $e^{qw2}$ is shown in the Euler's forumla extension?**

Comment: What is $x$?  Cheers!

Comment: Same as it is in Euler's formula with complex numbers, $e^{xi}$= $e^{x\sqrt{-1}}$ where $x$ is a real number.

Comment: More to the point, what is $\sqrt{-1}$? (In the quaternions, there are lots of solutions to $q^2=-1$).

Comment: For $d^ne^{nx\sqrt{-1}}$ it's just a simple complex number in Euler's Formula, which is then multiplied by the quaternion extended into Euler's Formula. Not sure if that's the way to write it out though.

Comment: The assumption was that due to quaternions being composed of one real plane and three imaginary planes a quaternion in Euler's form could be multiplied by a complex number set also in Euler's form.

Comment: I think that here $\sqrt{-1}$ refers to $(bi + cj + dk)/r$, whose square if I am not mistaken is $-1$; one square-root of $-1$ out of many in the quaternions.  The first of the related questions addresses this.

Comment: You are correct that for the quaternions extension $\frac{bi+cj+dk}{r}$ is a square root of −1.